# PHP using date() inside an SQL statement to use as file name

Tags: php, mysql

So im testing my codes and I SELECT data from my database. Now the select statemtent was successful. After selecting, i'd like to export the data to a csv file with a file name of the current date. But then it wont work when I use date() inside the sql statement. It works if I just put 123.csv as file name. can anyone help thank you very much. Here are my codes...

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "envoy");
function db_connect() {

  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("ERROR!");
  mysqli_select_db($db, DB_NAME);

  return $db;
}

$db = db_connect();
date_default_timezone_set("EST5EDT");
$date = date('m-d-Y');
echo $date;
$sql2 = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/junji/Desktop/'".$date."'.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM brochureinfo where sku LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' || name LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' ORDER BY name ";
$rs2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
mysqli_close($db);
```

so basically my everytime I refresh the page it should create a file no outputs whatsoever because I'm just testing the code. thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you need to fix this part of the $sql2 select:

```
"'.csv'
```

change it to this:

```
".csv'
```

I missed this the first time but I guess you fixed it:

```
'C:/Users/junji/Desktop/'"
```

should be:

```
'C:/Users/junji/Desktop/"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Charles nailed it. If you do some debugging, you'll catch this stuff real quick. To see for yourself, do a print_r($sql2) after the SELECT line. It will output the SQL statement you strung together - it is invalid SQL.

Comment: now my problem is the date is stored in the database as decimal numbers ughhhh. maybe you know the answer? THANKS!!

Comment: I don't see any code that would store the date in the database.  Is there more code you haven't posted?  If yes, edit your question and add the code.

Comment: I store dates and times in MySQL DATETIME columns all the time.  I have not problems, I just format it like this before inserting it: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your query, the single quote ( **'** ) isn't necessary before and after your variable $date.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/junji/Desktop/'".$date."'.csv' FIELDS TE... "
```

should be corrected as below

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/junji/Desktop/".$date.".csv' FIELDS TE... "
```